# Set a jobs build number to the same as the job the artifact was copied from

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a Jenkins job that compiles our developers code each time they push to the repository and stores the build as an artifact (lets call it CompileApp). I have another job that smoke tests that code, copying the latest successful artifact from the build. However it cannot run against every single build due to resource constraints (call this job SmokeTest).

So SmokeTest executes periodically and each time it does **I want to be able to set the build number of that job to the same build number of the CompileApp artifact** I copied so that it is clear which build was tested. (I will also add a timestamp to the build number incase no builds have completed within this timeframe)

I can set the build number with the [build name setter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) plugin which uses environment variables. But I am not sure how to access the CompileApp jobs build number using it. I have looked at the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin but haven't understood how to use it correctly.

Any advice and pointers would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use COPYARTIFACT_BUILD_NUMBER_*YOUR_JOB* variable, where *YOUR_JOB* is the name of original job.

Comment: It works. When your job name has spaces then instaed use _ sign

Answer (score 2):

Finally solved my problem by writing a small text file in the CompileApp job with the batch file command

> echo PARENT_BUILD_NUMBER=%BUILD_NUMBER% > envVariables.txt

I then archived that text file.

Then in the SmokeTest job I copied the artifact from CompileApp and imported it as an environment variable from the file using the EnvInject plugin in a build step. Then having an environment variable I use it to set the build name with the build name setter plugin with the command

> #${ENV,var="PARENT_BUILD_NUMBER"} ${ENV,var="BUILD_ID"}

The answer to this question was especially helpful to solve the problem [How to set environment variables in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins/10626193#10626193)

Answer (score 1):

[Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) is the plugin you're looking for. With this plugin you can pass the `BUILD_NUMBER` of the current job to the downstream job.

Comment: except then I have to execute the downstream job for every time the upstream job completes which I don't currently have the resources for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a downstream job, running in the same workspace of the build job, and when the integration test job is running, that it blocks the build job from executing.

You can then trigger the downstream smoke test job to run every 5/10 builds or so.

Comment: I'm not having a problem triggering builds, I want to be able to set the build number in the smoke test to the build number of the compiled app that I have tested

Answer (score 0):

Check this post: [How to convince jenkins to share a build number for several jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429061/how-to-convince-jenkins-to-share-a-build-number-for-several-jobs)

The key is to use "Evaluated Groovy Script" feature of the [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin to get a reference to any job. So in your case CompileApp job can set the nextBuildNumber for SmokeTestApp job.